# Can you get to the Ettenmoors if you're not a VIP?

Tags: lord-of-the-rings-online

Can you get to the Ettenmoors if you're not a VIP? Is their any exception if you're not VIP, can you use Turbine points to get there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the Rise of Isengard expansion, you will be able to play in the Ettenmoors (with some restrictions).

From [here](http://www.brighthub.com/video-games/mmo/articles/126037.aspx):

> The other big change in Rise of Isengard is PvMP. For the first time,
>   F2P (free to play) gamers can play in the Ettenmoors as a reaver (the
>   other monster classes cost Turbine points). Also, every monster class
>   skill is available for purchase regardless of rank, so the Ettenmoors
>   should see a large influx of new players testing it out. A recent
>   patch boosted monster players up with 40% more out of combat morale
>   regen and an across-the-board 20-30% DPS increase, making them much
>   more competitive against the free peoples.

Also, more information, from [here](http://lotro-wiki.com/index.php/Monster_Play):

> Before you are able to play Monster Play, you have to create a free
>   player and attain at least level 10. After that, a red "Monster Play"
>   button will be active on the character select screen after login
>   (Prior to Book 10, Fell Scrying Pools were used in-game; these have
>   been removed). In Monster Play, you have one slot for each class
>   available to play. Free players get only the Orc Reaver as free class,
>   the other classes cost 800 Turbine Points. The available classes are:
>   Orc Reaver, Orc Defiler, Spider Weaver, Uruk Blackarrow, Uruk
>   Warleader, or Warg Stalker (all of which start as level 75 monsters).
>   Once created, each monster character will persist and be available for
>   further play, unless you choose to reset it.

Answer (score 0):

Now you can enter in Ettenmoors with your freep too. Not sure, but you can spend 60 mithril coins to have 6h of access to Ettenmoors.